# Bookmarklet: Redirecting to m.*.* for Mobile Browsers & www.*.* for Desktop Browsers

Tags: javascript, opera, bookmarklet

Is there a JavaScript hack I could place in the URL field which would guide mobile browsers to `"m."` prefixes and guide my desktop to `"www."` prefixes, if I provide the `"<domain>.<root>"` suffix?

I think this would be useful for both Weave and Opera Link users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `window.location.href` is a property, not a method.

You're trying to set the browser location by code along the lines of:

```
window.location.href("http://www." + address)
```

What you should be using instead is

```
window.location.href = "http://www." + address;
```

If you change your bookmarklet accordingly, it seems to function correctly (i.e. it takes me to www.cnn.com when I paste it into my address bar).  I thought about posting the corrected code here but on reflection I think that would be patronising.

Answer (score 0):

A Working Script:

javascript:(function(){url="digg.com";if(screen.width<=480&&screen.height<=320){window.location.href="http://m."+url}else{window.location.href="http://www."+url}})()